# Is this circuit the right way to drive a piezo buzzer?

Tags: piezo-buzzer

I am trying to drive a piezo buzzer and came up with the following circuit. Am I doing it right?

[image]

Comment: The part number shows a magnetic buzzer. Which is correct? Have you referred to the datasheet and any app notes?

Comment: Where are your design specs?  why 5V on a 3V buzzer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You show no good reason for deviating from the specs in the [datasheet.](https://www.cuidevices.com/product/resource/cmt-4023s-smt-tr.pdf)

[image]

[image]

Stay within the specs.  Next time please include the specs in the question.

Also, an MMBT3904 does *not* have hFE>200 and the diode is essential.

A better choice is a small signal diode and https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/diodes-incorporated/BC847BW-7-F/1142228.

It depends how loud you need But it is rated for +/-3V or 3.0 Vp and not +5V/-1V, which might work but offset the coil from it's rated centre position or perhaps saturate the core and draw more current.